# Remember password by setting cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my page I have one Remember Me checkbox. When I check this, I want to se my password in browser cookie. Is it possible?
I have provided the statement as:

```
if ($remember=='yes') {
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $cookie =array(
        'name'   => 'username',
        'value'  => $username,
        'expire' => '1209600'
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

Comment: You *want* to see your password in your cookie? I suppose you like it when sites email you your *forgotten password* too?

Comment: What the other commenters are trying to say: Don't do this please! Use another method of automatically letting users log in, storing a password in plaintext is NEVER a good option.

Comment: @gnur: You might want to look at some tutorial how remember cookie works.

Comment: @shakti singh: Most sites that allow you to stay logged in do not store your credentials as plain text. Mostly they'll use some kind of hash to determine wether your login is valid. If I find any site that stores my password in plain text as a cookie I'll seriously consider not visiting that site ever again!

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you should never store an unencrypted password in a cookie is that cookie theft in that case will provide permanent access. If you store hashed version, then it might be possible to impersonate a user as long as the cookie is valid, but the attacker won't have any way to log back in again once that cookie is invalidated.

In short: never store plain text informations in the client's browser, always use (possibly salted and/or signed) hashes both for passwords and usernames.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

check out this site, [Using Cookies in PHP - User Logon](http://www.phpnerds.com/article/using-cookies-in-php/2)

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 

    if(isset($_COOKIE['Joe2Torials'])) 
    { 
    $dbHost = 'localhost'; 
    $dbUser = 'root'; 
    $dbPass = ''; 
    $dbname = 'myshop'; 
    $username = $_COOKIE['Joe2Torials']['username']; 
    $password = $_COOKIE['Joe2Torials']['password']; 
    $db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);

    $query = "SELECT user, pass FROM login WHERE user = '$username' AND pass = '$password'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) 
    { 
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1; 

    header('Location:admin.php'); 
    exit(); 
    } 
    } 
?> 

<form method="post" name="cookie" action="process.php"> 

<p><label for="username">Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></label></p> 
<p><label for="password">Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></label></p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" name="setcookie" value="setcookie" /> Remember Me</p> 

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></p> 
</form> 

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['error']) AND !empty($_GET['error'])) 
{ 
echo 'Invalid login data supplied. Please try again.'; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

ya it is posible .. u can remember your password by setting `cookie`
[See this videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPX_g_hcuH8)

Comment: if ($remember=='yes')
       {
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $cookie =array(
                           'name'   => 'username',
                           'value'  => $username,
                           'expire' => '1209600'
            );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);           
        
       }